# Exception Caught: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Tags: mysql

Running ExpressionEngine 5.1.3, php 7.2 on Dreamhost shared server.

This error has brought our site down repeatedly for hours at a time over the last few days. We cannot access the site backend or any front end pages - just see the error. We made no recent configuration changes to the site. The complete error is like so:

```
Exception Caught
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared: SELECT LOWER(module_name) AS module_name, module_version, has_cp_backend, module_id FROM (`exp_modules`)

mysqli_connection.php:117
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You might be out of luck. Most likely, Dreamhost upgraded the MySQL version on that shared server and it isn't compatible with EE. Really, I would guess that when they upgraded, MySQL changed some default values for settings that are affecting you.

This may not be the case, but you should reach out to Dreamhost and see if they've deployed any upgrades recently. Unfortunately, if they have, it would seem very unlikely that they will mess with a shared server setting just for you and will just offer to move you to a better (and more expensive) hosting tier.

I do use Dreamhost from time to time, but I honestly wouldn't recommend a shared server of any type for a production instance of any application. I understand that things can be expensive, but I really wouldn't cheap out on hosting.